# change value when checked

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am new into HTML DOM . I am trying to change value when check-box checked.
So here is my unfinished script:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var val=12;
document.write("<p>"+val+"</p>");
function checkAddress()
{
    var chkBox = document.getElementById('checkAddress');
    if (chkBox.checked)
    {
        var val=val+2;
    }
}
function checkAddress2()
{
    var chkBox = document.getElementById('checkAddress2');
    if (chkBox.checked)
    {
        var val=val+3;
    }
}
function checkAddress3()
{
    var chkBox = document.getElementById('checkAddress3');
    if (chkBox.checked)
    {
        var val=val+4;
    }
}
</script>
<p>Get value :<input type="checkbox" id="checkAddress" name="checkAddress"    onclick="checkAddress()" value="1st"/>
Get value :<input type="checkbox" id="checkAddress2" name="checkAddress" onclick="checkAddress2()" value="2nd"/>
Get value :<input type="checkbox" id="checkAddress3" name="checkAddress" onclick="checkAddress3()" value="3rd"/>
```

Here, i just want to make this script: when checkbox click it will change the value auto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off your declaring val within the {} each time which means the value is lost.

Secondly, you don't do anything with val in order for it to be useful.

Finally, you could have one function instead of three where you pass the specific checkbox that was clicked.

Additionally,as stated in the comments you do not assign val to any elements (using .innerHtml, textarea, etc). Which means value is not seen.

```
 <html>

<script type="text/javascript">
var val=12;

function resetCheckboxes()
{
document.getElementById("checkAddress").checked=false;
document.getElementById("checkAddress2").checked=false;
document.getElementById("checkAddress3").checked=false;
}

function checkAddress(chkBox)
{
    var multiplyer = 1;

    if (!chkBox.checked)
    multiplyer = -1;

    if(chkBox.id =="checkAddress")
    val=val+ (multiplyer)*2;

    else if(chkBox.id =="checkAddress2")
    val=val+ (multiplyer)*3;

    else if(chkBox.id =="checkAddress3")
    val=val+ (multiplyer)*4;

    document.getElementById("displayValue").innerHTML = "Val:"+val;
}
</script>

<body onLoad="resetCheckboxes()">
<div id="displayValue">Val:12</div>
<p>Get value :<input type="checkbox" id="checkAddress" name="checkAddress"    onclick="checkAddress(this)" value="1st"/>
Get value :<input type="checkbox" id="checkAddress2" name="checkAddress" onclick="checkAddress(this)" value="2nd"/>
Get value :<input type="checkbox" id="checkAddress3" name="checkAddress" onclick="checkAddress(this)" value="3rd"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for advice.
I mentioned that it is unfinished script. try to complete this.
I just wanna show the value first. then when checkbox checked then value will be changed.

Comment: Thanks. but i actually need to create 3 function cause for function 1 will be add 2 but rest will add 3 and 4. 

But Is it possible to get back previous value when un-checked ? May be not with this solution ?

Comment: actually i don't know `innerHTML` will be suitable for this. Cause if checkbox will click then add 2 or else. and after unchecked it will be set previous. and it is not possible by `innerHTML` . isn't that ?

Comment: Thanks. 
one matter, is it possible to get back previous value when unchecked ? 
May be it should here use jQuery. or p[ossible in javascript DOM ?

Comment: Exclusive ! Nice it's working as like i want. 

Thanks meewoK

Comment: I have research a while with your solution. Again, it's really amazing. Thanks a lot.